# NoSuchFieldException on executing ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("libraries") in Java 17

Tags: java-17

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: libraries
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2610)
```

Wondering how Eclipse-debug is able to access and display the values:

[Eclipse-debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYSpb.png)

Working fine though, in Java 11:

```
Field nativeLibsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("nativeLibraries");
nativeLibsField.setAccessible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 12 a filter was introduced for access to fields via reflection of the following classes:

```
java.lang.ClassLoader
java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject
java.lang.reflect.Constructor
java.lang.reflect.Field
java.lang.reflect.Method
```

You can see the issue in the [issue tracker](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8210522). This is the [commit](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/9c70e26c146ae4c5a2e2311948efec9bf662bb8c), that introduced this change in OpenJDK.

I don't actually know this, but I guess that Eclipse is using the Java Debugging Interface instead of reflection to access this information.